# How to re-write one fraction as two others.

Tags: laplace-transform, fractions, partial-fractions

I have the two following fractions.

$$ \dfrac{A}{Bx^{\alpha+1}}$$ and $$ \dfrac{C}{Dx^{\alpha+\beta}}$$
The form i want
$$ \dfrac{E}{Fx^{\alpha+\beta+1}}$$

I was thinking to do partial fractions or potentially doing a Laplace or Fourier transform, then rearranging and transforming back. How could one possibly get the two fractions into one fraction of this form.\
$ A,B,C,D,E$ and $F$ can be number or possible a factorial if we go down the laplace transform route, as can $\alpha, \beta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming, as you seem to have implied, that $A,B,C,D,E,F$ are arbitrary, and, in particular, that $E$ and $F$ can be defined as some combination of $A,B,C,D$.
$$
\frac{A}{Bx^{\alpha+1}}=\frac{A}{Bx^{\alpha+1}}\cdot\frac{x^\beta}{x^\beta}=
\frac{Ax^\beta}{Bx^{\alpha+1}x^\beta}=\frac{Ax^\beta}{Bx^{\alpha+\beta+1}}
$$
And, similarly,
$$
\frac{C}{Dx^{\alpha+\beta}}=\frac{Cx}{Dx^{\alpha+\beta+1}}
$$
So you can have
$$
\frac{Ax^\beta}{Bx^{\alpha+\beta+1}}-\frac{Cx}{Dx^{\alpha+\beta+1}}\cdot x^{\beta-1}=
\frac{Ax^\beta}{Bx^{\alpha+\beta+1}}-\frac{Cx^{\beta}}{Dx^{\alpha+\beta+1}}=
\frac{AD-BC}{BDx^{\alpha+\beta+1}}
$$
and thus, we can let $E=AD-BC$ and $F=BD$ to get
$$
\frac{E}{Fx^{\alpha+\beta+1}}=\left(\frac{A}{Bx^{\alpha+1}}\right)-
\left(\frac{C}{Dx^{\alpha+\beta}}\right)x^{\beta-1}
$$

#### Edit:

This also shows that you cannot get appropriate values of $E,F$ from a linear combination. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that there are constants $M,N$ such that
$$
M\left(\frac{A}{Bx^{\alpha+1}}\right)+N\left(\frac{C}{Dx^{\alpha+\beta}}\right)=
\frac{E_1}{F_1x^{\alpha+\beta+1}}
$$
for some $E_1,F_1$. Then we have
$$
\frac{E/E_1}{F/F_1}\left(M\left(\frac{A}{Bx^{\alpha+1}}\right)+
N\left(\frac{C}{Dx^{\alpha+\beta}}\right)\right)=
\frac{E/E_1}{F/F_1}\frac{E_1}{F_1x^{\alpha+\beta+1}}=\frac{E}{Fx^{\alpha+\beta+1}}
$$
For simplicity, let $\epsilon=\frac{E/E_1}{F/F_1}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\epsilon M\left(\frac{A}{Bx^{\alpha+1}}\right)+
\epsilon N\left(\frac{C}{Dx^{\alpha+\beta}}\right)&=
\left(\frac{A}{Bx^{\alpha+1}}\right)-
\left(\frac{C}{Dx^{\alpha+\beta}}\right)x^{\beta-1}\\
\epsilon M\left(\frac{A}{Bx^{\alpha+1}}\right)&=
\left(\frac{A}{Bx^{\alpha+1}}\right)-
\left(\frac{C}{Dx^{\alpha+\beta}}\right)\left(x^{\beta-1}+\epsilon N\right)\\
\epsilon M&=1-\left(\frac{BC}{ADx^{\beta-1}}\right)\left(x^{\beta-1}+\epsilon N\right)\\
\epsilon M&=1-\frac{\epsilon BCN}{ADx^{\beta-1}}\\
M&=\frac{1}{\epsilon}-\frac{BCN}{ADx^{\beta-1}}
\end{align}
And this contradicts the assumption that $M$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you very much, I follow this apart from when you say "so you can have", i dont see how you can multiply by $x^{\beta-1}$ without changing the expression.

Comment: @MathsPro The expression at that point is just something I created to combine the two fractions to get the desired powers of $x$ is the numerator and denominator, allowing me to define$\frac{E}{Fx^{\alpha+\beta+1}}$ at the end. It isn't really "changed" from anything, because it's new. If you want to define the last fraction as a strictly linear combination of the first two, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Yes i was looking for a linear combination if possible, thank you for your efforts

Comment: @MathsPro It's definitely impossible. I have added a proof of this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I properly understood (which is not sure, I must confess) : let $$P=\frac{A}{Bx^{\alpha+1}}$$ $$Q=\frac{C}{Dx^{\alpha+\beta}}$$ So $$P^{\frac{1}{\alpha+1}}=\Big(\frac{A}{B}\Big)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+1}}\frac 1x$$  $$P^{\frac{1}{\alpha+1}}Q=\Big(\frac{A}{B}\Big)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+1}}\Big(\frac CD \Big)\frac{1}{x^{\alpha+\beta+1}}=\dfrac{E}{Fx^{\alpha+\beta+1}}$$ So $$\dfrac{E}{F}=\Big(\frac{A}{B}\Big)^{\frac{1}{\alpha+1}}\Big(\frac CD\Big)$$ You can choose any value you want for $E$ or $F$ and compute the other one from the above equation.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, however i was looking  for somthing where to take the two functions, and by adding give you an expression in for form of E and F